# When view is removed from superview all animations are removed or not?

Tags: ios, core-animation

1. I add an endlessly repeating animation to view_A.
2. The animation starts.
3. I swap view_A out of its superview for view_B.
4. The animation on view_A stops — I can tell that in my `animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method — and I can see `[view_A.layer animationForKey:theAnimationKey]` is `nil`, `view_A.layer.animationKeys` is `nil` and `view_A.layer.animations`(print view_A.layer in GDB can reveal that) is empty. (**Question 1**: Are all animations removed automatically when view is removed from its superview?)
5. I swap view_A back. Here comes the odd thing: I see the animation is still going. (**Question 2**: how could the animation keep going after it is stopped and removed from its view?)
6. The even more bizarre thing is that I *can* stop the animation after step 5 by calling `[view_A.layer removeAnimationForKey:theAnimationKey]`!

Comment: In step 4, was the boolean finished YES or NO?

Comment: @FaisalMemon NO. I guess it is because the animation is interrupted when the view is removed from the window. But it is still going on when the view is added back to the window. Very odd.

Comment: What is removedOnCompletion property value, and did you get multiple animationDidStart calls?

Comment: @FaisalMemon YES. No.

Comment: @FaisalMemon I believe it is Core Animation bug. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug of Core Animation. Here is my radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6165852231565312.